# JQuery Validate dropdown selection on Button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble validating a drop down asp control on button click. I have a panel that contains radio buttons, textboxes, a drop down, and a save button. If the radio button for zip is chosen a drop down list appears (that is binded with data in the code behind) and you must select a zip from the list. I'm having trouble validating on button click of the save button that a selection was made from the downdown list.
I would like to do it with jQuery  and tried doing it like so that pops up and alert but its not working. Like to have it validate the selection before it does on the onClick of the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_submit').click(function() {
        if ($('#ZIPDD').val() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Please select a zip.');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP6" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <table style="text-align:center;" cellpadding="5px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table runat="server" id="_table" width="100%" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:inherit;" valign="middle">
                            <div>STEP 1:</div>
                            <div>Enter a #</div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" style=" margin-bottom:15px;">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_nbr" Width="70px"/>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Continue" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:15px;" valign="middle">                              
                        </td>
                        <td style="border:2px solid gray; background-color:Silver;">
                            <table runat="server" id="SHTable" visible="false" width="100%">
                                <tr align="left">
                                    <th style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;">Methods</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;">Location</th>
                                    <th style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;">&nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" ID="DOTEXT"></asp:Label></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr align="left">
                                    <td>
                                        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;"><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ZIP" Text="ZIP" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ZIP_CheckedChanged" /></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:300px;">
                                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ZIPDD" Visible="false"/><br /><asp:Label ID="ziplabel" Visible="false" runat="server" style="color: red; font-size:12px;"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:15px;" valign="middle">
                            <div>Confirm changes and hit save</div>    
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                            <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="btn_submit" OnClick="btn_submit_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Binding to the dropdown in the code behind on page load

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ZIPDD.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        Loadzips();
    }
}
private void LoadBranches()
{
    using (SqlConnection SQLCONN)
    {
        SQLCONN.Open();
        SqlCommand SQLCOMM = SQLCONN.CreateCommand();
        SQLCOMM.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
        IDataReader dr = SQLCOMM.ExecuteReader();
        ZIPDD.DataSource = dr;
        ZIPDD.DataValueField = "ZIPID";
        ZIPDD.DataTextField = "ZIPLABEL";
        ZIPDD.DataBind();
        ZIPDD.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
        ZIPDD.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your click function being executed at all?

Comment: everytime I run it and try and test it just goes right through to the onclick function in the code behind but I chose val==0 which is a 'blank' row in the drop down list.

Comment: "If the radio button for zip is chosen a drop down list appears" In your current setup the click is bound to the submit button, which means it will just send the form, not provide an additional form dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are planning to use javascript/jquery, pay attention to how controls are rendered in the client side. You are setting `visible="false"` to table and controls, they will never render in the client side. You can't find them using jquery. To work properly, you need to set this:

```
<table runat="server" id="SHTable" visible="false" width="100%">
```

to this:

```
<table runat="server" id="SHTable" style="display:none" width="100%">
```

and also change this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ZIPDD" Visible="false"/>
```

to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ZIPDD" style="display:none"/>
```

To test your script, set `style="display:block"` for the table and the dropdown also, otherwise you will see porpup to select a zip (dropdown value is 0).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you look at using the jQuery.validate plugin. It will validate all form items that have the class "required" attached to it. You could use jQuery and addClass to add the class required to the dropdown if the checkbox is highlighted.

```
if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { 
$( ".dropDownClassIdentifier" ).addClass( "required" );
}
else
{
$( ".dropDownClassIdentifier" ).removeClass( "required" );
}
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/ and
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ are good places to start looking for documentation